# Can't camelcase UTF-8 character

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8, camelcasing

I am dealing with words that start with letters like "ú". I want to convert them to camelcase in the DB or at least display them camelized. Eg: ú => Ú.

```
>> cit.name
=> "újváros"
>> cit.name.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
>> cit.name.valid_encoding?
=> true
>> cit.name.encode("UTF-8")
=> "újváros"
>> cit.name.camelcase
=> "újváros"
>> cit.name.camelize
=> "újváros"
>> cit.name.mb_chars.camelcase.to_s
=> "újváros"
>> cit.name.upcase
=> "úJVáROS" #sweet isn't it? :)
>> cit.update_attributes(:name => cit.name.camelcase)
(16.4ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true
>> cit.name
=> "újváros"
>> cit.name.ord
=> 250
```

I would need decimal code point 218:
http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C3%9A&mode=char

Hope someone can crack this.

TIA!

Comment: `"újváros".mb_chars.titlecase.to_s`? ` => "Újváros"`

Comment: Hi julp, yeapp, that did the trick. Big thanks. If you add it as answer I will mark it as solution.